# Change ad transition animation

Tags: java, android, animation, transition, ads

Is there a way to set the transition animation from a interstitial ad being closed to the activity that initiated it. For example

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in_c, R.anim.fade_out_c);
}
```

I use this for when an activity is closed

Answer (score -1):

Might you can use that in ***onAdClosed()***

```
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in_c, R.anim.fade_out_c);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ad is closed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```